# How to identify and store a specific string from a dynamic google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've got a specific issue I can't seem to find a solution for. I'm trying to identify a specific string (finnkode) found in the markers of a dynamic google map.

The google maps is on this site: http://www.finn.no/finn/realestate/pulse/priceinfo/
under the tab "Solgte boliger". (Zoom in to the red area which represents the capital Oslo)

The map shows either specific "properties" or aggregated properties(marked with a pluss sign).  If you click on one of the icons a pop-up window appears with a link to the specific property. In this link a "finnkode" is stored. I want to identify all available finnkodes and store then in a database.

Currently I have found no way to do this? I hope someone can help

[image: example of map view of Oslo]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each property overlay box is stored on the html page like this:

```
<map id="poiImageMap-1" name="poiImageMap-1">
<area id="poi_93955716" class="type_10002 group" shape="rect" coords="630,168,646,184" title="FINN-eiendom-solgt" href="">
<area id="poi_93955715" class="type_10002 group" shape="rect" coords="578,50,594,66" title="FINN-eiendom-solgt" href="">
[...]
</map>
```

And once you click on one of the overlays, the box pops up that contains the information you want, and is displayed somewhere in the html code (example too long to post here).

You could write a parser to scrape through this page, clicking each overlay and then recording the data that appears in the popup box.

Comment: that is what I need support to do... if you can help with a doable code, that would be highly appreciated. thx

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is a LOT of work. I'm not going to code the entire solution for you. Attempt it yourself and then if you have any problems, come back to SO.